# Custom size iPad Split view

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad

Im fairly new to objective C. I am currently trying to implement a split view on the iPad. I would like to have a left side view that can be resized so that it looks more like the side view on the spotify app for the ipad.

I understand UI Split controllers won't work because their width's are fixed.

I understand the other option is to use a View controller with sub views that can resized as required. However, I am not too sure how I should implement each subview with its own navigation controller. Any suggestions how else I can implement the said feature.

The image of the side panel implementation can be found in [this link](http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02209/spotify1_2209751b.jpg).

Comment: you should start it with good tutorial of `UIViewController` and `UIView` classes and their hierarchy first, I guess...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Matt Gemmell's [MGSplitViewController](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController) to accomplish this. It provides a custom split view controller implementation that might let you do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to recommend, [PSStackedView](https://github.com/steipete/PSStackedView) which i have used to create a similar layout as the Spotify iPad app. Took some time to understand it